# jQuery Issue about Continue button opens external link in multiple browser tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing one feature about showing alert on external link(apart from current domain) click. For that, I have written below code. All is working fine except below scenario.

```
$('a').each(function() {            
            var $a  = jQuery(this);         
            if ($a.get(0).hostname && getDomain($a.get(0).hostname) != currentDomain) {
                $a.click(function(event) {                  
                    //console.log($a.get(0));
                    //var myClasses = this.classList;
                    //console.log(myClasses.length + " " + myClasses['0']);

                    $("#redirectconfirm-modal").removeClass('hide');
                    if (!confirmed) {                       
                        event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopPropagation();

                        $modal.on('show', function() {
                            $modal.find('.btn-continue').click(function() {                                             
                                confirmed = true;
                                $a.get(0).click();
                                $modal.modal('hide');
                                location.reload();
                            });
                        });

                        $modal.on('hide', function() {                                                          
                            $a.get(0).removeClass("selected");
                            confirmed = false;
                        });
                        $modal.modal('show');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

**Scenario which produces this issue:**

- Click on any external link from the site, it open a modal popup for redirection confirmation with continue & return button.
- If I click on "Return" button it closes the modal popup.
- Now, I am clicking on external link from my site, it open the modal again but this time I am clicking on "Continue" button & guess what, it open that external link in 3 different tabs

Actually on each anchor tag click, it saves whole anchor tag value. I think, if remove all these anchor tag values on modal close code i.e.  $modal.on('hide', function() { }) it will resolve problem. I had tried with many different ways but still facing this issue.

Can you please provide solution/suggestion on that?

Answer (score 0):

Don't inline your events, you may try something like this:

```
$('a').each(function() {   //add a class to all external links         
    var $a  = jQuery(this);         
    if ($a.get(0).hostname && getDomain($a.get(0).hostname) != currentDomain) {
        $a.addClass('modalOpen');
    }
});
$('.modalOpen').not(".selected").click(function(event) {  //open the modal if you click on a external link
       event.preventDefault();
        $('.modalOpen').addClass('selected'); //add class selected to it            
        $modal.modal('show');
});
$modal.on('hide', function() {                                                          
    $('.selected').removeClass("selected");//remove the class if you close the modal
});
$('.btn-continue').click(function() {                                             
    $('.selected').click();//if the users clicks on continue open the external link and hide the modal
    $modal.modal('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is when you have 3 external links (as you probably have), than you set 3 times this part of code:

```
$modal.on('show', function() { ... });
$modal.on('hide', function() { ... });
```

which is wrong. Those events listeners should be set only once.

Some simplified code would look like this:

```js
var $modal = $("#redirectconfirm-modal");
var currentDomain = 'blabla';
$modal.on('click', '.btn-continue', function(e) {
    window.location = $modal.data('redirectTo');
});
$('a').each(function() {
    var $a = jQuery(this);
    if( $a.get(0).hostname && getDomain($a.get(0).hostname)!=currentDomain ) {
        $a.click(function(e) {
   $modal.data('redirectTo', $a.attr('href'));
            $modal.modal('show');
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: he is not sending the events he is listening to them

Comment: using this code, a modal popup is not opened, it directly redirect to external link

Comment: you cannot use this code as is... it is just a structure (your domain name is not blabla, etc).